# Cómo devolver el name en un select en lugar del id con Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy armando un sistema web con Django(última versión a la fecha), y tengo que armar los formularios para cargar ciertos datos.
El sistema se trata de un registro de cheques, cuentas bancarias y bancos, para poder trabajar con fechas y demás.

Tengo que resolver algunos detalles. Uno de ellos es que tengo armado un modelo para cargar en la base de datos, los datos de un banco. A continuación tengo otro formulario para registrar los números de cuentas bancarias, que pertencen a los bancos ya cargados, los cuales se cargan en la base de datos con el ID del banco y el respectivo número de cuenta.

La cuestión es que en el formulario, el select de los bancos me devuelve el ID y necesito que me devuelva el nombre, aunque en el value, debería ir el ID (cuyo valor ya se encuentra)

Esto es el **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from apps.persons.models import *

# Create your models here.

    class Banco(models.Model):
        bankId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        bankName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    class CuentasCorriente(models.Model):
        nroCuenta = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        bankId = models.ForeignKey(Banco, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        email = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Esto sería el **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from apps.persons import urls
from .models import *
from .forms import *

# Create your views here.

    def bancos(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
    
            bancos = Banco.objects.all()
    
            form = BancoForm()
            if request.method == "POST":
                form = BancoForm(request.POST)
    
                if form.is_valid():
                    instancia = form.save(commit=False)
                    instancia.save()
                    return redirect('bancos')
            return render(request, 'banks.html', {'form': form, 'bancos': bancos})
        return redirect('login')
    
    def cuentas(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            form = CuentasCorrienteForm()
            if request.method == "POST":
                form = CuentasCorriente(request.POST)
    
                if form.is_valid():
                    instacia = form.save(commit=False)
                    instancia.save()
                    return redirect('cuentas')
            return render(request, 'accounts.html', {'form': form})
        return redirect('login')
```

Esto sería el **forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Banco, CuentasCorriente, Cheque

# from .urls import reverse

class BancoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Banco
        fields = ['bankName']
        labels = {'bankName': 'Nombre del Banco'}
        widgets = {'bankName': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'class':'form-control col-6'})}

class CuentasCorrienteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CuentasCorriente
        fields = ['bankId', 'nroCuenta']
        labels = {'bankId': 'Banco', 'nroCuenta': 'Número de Cuenta'}
        bankName = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Banco.objects.all(), required=True)
        widgets = {
            'bankId': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control col-6'}),
            'nroCuenta': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control col-6'})
            }
```

**EDIT**

Muestro el template de la vista:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% block title %}Cuentas{% endblock %}
{% block main %}

<section id="services" class="section-bg">
  <div class="container my-5">
    <div class="md-6 lg-4 wow bounceInUp" data-wow-duration="1.4s">
      <div class="box">

        <div class="icon" style="background: #fceef3;"><i class="ion-android-document" style="color: #ff689b;"></i></div>
        <h4 class="title"><a href="www.facebook.com">Cuentas</a></h4>
        <div class="form-container">
          <div id="login" class="col s12">
            <form class="text-left" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                {% csrf_token %}
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar Cuenta Corriente</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Necesitas que en el template (el html) muestre en el select el nombre del banco? si es así podrías compartir la parte del código del template que tiene ese select para poder ayudarte.

Comment: muestro el template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres que te regrese el nombre del banco y no solo el ID, prueba agregando la funcion `__str__` a tu clase **Banco** para recuperar el valor almacenado en la variable del nombre, es decir:

```
class Banco(models.Model):
        bankId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        bankName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        
        def __str__(self):
        return 'El nombre del banco es: {}'.format(self.bankName)
```

Espero te haya ayudado, saludos.